# How does this syntax work: print("Hello", end="")

Tags: python, function, syntax

In python, I found I can have no new lines after printing by doing: `print("something", end="")`, how does this syntax where you say `end=something` work, and how and why would you want to have it in your own function declaration.
Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I don't know what this syntax is called.

Comment: have you tried looking it up in the python documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is called keyword arguments (or named arguments). This is explained in the official Python tutorial here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

And the print documentation is here.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

If you still have questions after reading these documents, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

It tells the `print` function to end the line with an empty string, rather than a newline.

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html